# Changing @property value of self while executing a block that uses a strong reference to self

Tags: ios, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, nsblockoperation, strong-references

I'm working on doing network requests in my app and am using NSBlockOperations in an NSOperationQueue to do this asynchronously. However, I want to be able to cancel these operations if the view controller that called them is deallocated (has been popped off the navigation stack).

This is a simplified version of what I have:

```
NSArray *posts;

__weak DataController *weakSelf = self;
NSBlockOperation *fetchPostsOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    DataController *strongSelf = weakSelf;
    NSDictionary *response = [weakSelf refreshPostsInPart:PartFirst];
    posts = [response objectForKey:@"posts"];
}];

[self.queue addOperation:fetchPostsOperation];
```

In the  `refreshPostsInPart:` method of DataController I make repeated network requests for paginated data from App.net using a while loop. At each iteration of the loop I check a property of DataController `self.isCancelled` (of type BOOL), if it is `NO` I keep making requests.

In my `dealloc` method of DataController I set this property to be `YES` so that on the next iteration of the while loop I will stop making requests. In essence, I'm implementing a poor mans `cancelAllOperations` while using NSBlockOperation.

Question: When setting `self.isCancelled` to `NO` in my dealloc method, am I also setting `self.isCancelled` for the strongSelf reference that is being used in the block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self`, `weakSelf`, and `strongSelf` all refer to the same object in memory. That means that if you send a message to `self` in `dealloc` (which you do by setting that property), `weakSelf` and `strongSelf` also "know" about this updated property. So, yes, you are setting `self.isCancelled` (more than likely the actual property's name is `self.cancelled` and its getter is `isCancelled`) on `strongSelf` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I thought this was the case but lacked the solid knowledge to back it up.